# Run Haskell benchmarks on inputs of varying size

Tags: haskell, graph, benchmarking, time-complexity, haskell-criterion

Often I’d like to compare the runtime performance of multiple implementations of the same function. For individual inputs, criterion is a good tool.

But what is an easy way to plot the performance of the code over varying input size, e.g. to see the algorithmic complexity?

Ideally, I pass the library a value of type `Benchmarkable r => [(String, Int -> r)]`, i.e. a list of size-dependent benchmarks, and the library will automatically find a the sensible input range for each value and creates a nice plot from it.

Answer (score 8):

> e.g. to see the algorithmic complexity?

There's a package for that:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/complexity

However, I typically use QuickCheck to drive testing at random data sizes, then plot the result.

Comment: Too bad, it seems the package has bit-rotted; its dependency hstats does not build in GHC 7.6.

Comment: You're telling me, I patched that a year ago...  but it isn't hard to fix, for anyone else reading - just get the version from github until the author uploads a new version (some time 2014 perhaps?)